# Azure Dev Ops Build fail

Tags: azure-devops

I am new to Pipelines.

I am getting this error on a pipeline.

C:\Program Files\dotnet\sdk\5.0.103\Sdks\Microsoft.NET.Sdk\targets\Microsoft.PackageDependencyResolution.targets(241,5): Error NETSDK1004: Assets file 'C:\agent_work\26\s\Lawman2008\LawmanSolution\Lawman.DataLibrary\obj\project.assets.json' not found. Run a NuGet package restore to generate this file.

I thought it was the version of the Nuget. So I set it to use Nuget 5.8.0. Also tried 5.8.x. Previous was 4.4.1

I renamed the build folder to old to force it to recreate a new folder. Which it did.

The project is .NET Standard 2.0.

Looking in the netstandard2.0 folder under bin/debug and obj/debug there are no files.

[image]

Comment: Please share your pipeline so we can provide you a better answer.

Comment: I have added a command line script just before the Build solution dotnet restore C:\agent\_work\26\s\Lawman2008\LawmanSolution\Lawman.DataLibrary\Lawman.DataLibrary.csproj. This has solved it but why does the Nuget Restore not do it.